# Spring Cloud Zuul: Apply filter only to specific route

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using Spring Cloud's Zuul to proxy some API requests to a few external servers. The proxying itself works well, but each service requires a (different) token provided in the request header.

I've successfully written a simple pre filter for each token that applies the appropriate header. However, I now have a problem. Even after pouring through the documentation, I can't figure out how to make each filter apply only to the proper route. I don't want to perform url-matching as the url changes across environments. Ideally, I'd have some way to get the name of the route in the filter.

My application.yml:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    foo:
      path: /foo/**
      url: https://fooserver.com
    bar:
      path: /bar/**
      url: https://barserver.com
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like this in FooFilter.java (a prefilter):

```
public bool shouldFilter() {
    return RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRouteName().equals("foo");
}
```

but I can't seem to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `proxy` header in `RequestContext` to distinguish routed server like below. If you are using ribbon, you can also use `serviceId` header. But if you specify url direclty like above your example, you should use `proxy` header. One thing you have to know is that `proxy` header is set in `PreDecorationFilter`, so your pre-filter must have bigger value of filter order than the value that `PreDecorationFilter` has (it is 5 at this moment).

```
@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    if ((ctx.get("proxy") != null) && ctx.get("proxy").equals("foo")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe how hard this was to find! Thanks!

Comment: Minor comment: if could be simplified with 
    "foo".equals( ctx.get( "proxy" )

Comment: Where can I find the details about the order number given in filter?

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan You can find the order here - FileConstants.java https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/support/FilterConstants.java#L78

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE and unfortunately it does not work, there is no "proxy" object associated with RequestContext. Any other idea?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.0. and it contains the "proxy" object. Just FYI.